# Table Line above?

Tags: tables, rules

```
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Register Table} \label{tab:title} 
\begin{tabulary}{1.2\textwidth}{| p{3cm} || C | p{3cm} | C | C p{1cm} | }
Procedure        & Expected Outcome         & Pass or Fail           \\ \hline
1. Click on Register button when one or more fields are empty   & An error message should     error beside affected fields       & yes  \\ \hline          
\end{tabulary}  
\end{center}
```

Struggling with organising this table, i.e. getting the very top line to draw on top of the rows? Also any ideas on why the pass or fail column text is positioned to the far left when I need it in the center?

Comment: Please complement your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, including *only* the packages necessary to reproduce the issue. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what’s wrong when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You have specified that your table is wider than your page (which will make TeX issue warnings) and you have specified 6 columns but your first row only has three entries, which isn't an error but means the second three entries will be blank. `pass or fail` is in `p{3cm}` so it is set as a justified paragraph.

Comment: The top line can be added via `\hline` just as usual.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This corrects the number of columns and the total width and adds another line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,capt-of}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Register Table} \label{tab:title} 
\begin{tabulary}{1.2\textwidth}{| p{3cm} || C | p{3cm} | C | C p{1cm} | }
Procedure        & Expected Outcome         & Pass or Fail           \\ \hline
1. Click on Register button when one or more fields are empty   & An error message should     error beside affected fields       & yes  \\ \hline          
\end{tabulary}  
\end{center}


\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{Register Table} \label{tab:title} 
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{| C | C | C| }
\hline
Procedure        & Expected Outcome         & Pass or Fail           \\ \hline
1. Click on Register button when one or more fields are empty   & An error message should     error beside affected fields       & yes  \\ \hline          
\end{tabulary}  
\end{center}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `booktabs` package, which provides different line types. Instead of `\hline` you can use `\toprule`, `\midrule` or `\bottomrule`. However, the documentation of the package ([`texdoc booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booktabs)) provides useful information about layout of tables. Here is a short quote from chapter 2:

> You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all
>   times:
>
> 1. Never, ever use vertical rules.
> 2. Never use double rules.
>
> These guidelines may seem extreme but I have never found a good
>   argument in favour of breaking them.

Comment: I think it would be good to present a code snippet, better a complete MWE, how to do this ...